# How to use addr2line in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, native-code, addr2line

I am stuck with my app, as I am unable to debug as it is a multithreaded one and crashes with error SIGSEGV. I get lot of information from LogCat, which gives me addresses in my native library. It would be helpful if I could convert these addresses into my code.

Does anybody have any idea how to use addr2line, which is provided with android-ndk?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Let's say that logcat show you the following crash log (this is from one of my projects):

```
I/DEBUG   (   31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:2.3/GRH55/79397:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   31): pid: 378, tid: 386  >>> com.example.gltest <<<
I/DEBUG   (   31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r0 001dbdc0  r1 00000001  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r4 00000000  r5 40a40000  r6 4051a480  r7 42ddbee8
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r8 43661b24  r9 42ddbed0  10 42ddbebc  fp 41e462d8
I/DEBUG   (   31):  ip 00000001  sp 436619d0  lr 83a12f5d  pc 8383deb4  cpsr 20000010
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #00  pc 0003deb4  /data/data/com.example.gltest/lib/libnativemaprender.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #01  pc 00039b76  /data/data/com.example.gltest/lib/libnativemaprender.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #02  pc 00017d34  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

Look at the last 3 lines; this is your callstack. 'pc' is the program counter, and the pc for stack frame #00 gives you the address where the crash occurred. This is the number to pass to addr2line.

I'm using NDK r5, so the executable I'm using is located at `$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin`; make sure that is in your `$PATH`. The command to use looks like

```
arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line -C -f -e obj/local/armeabi/libXXX.so <address>
```

Or, for the case above:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line -C -f -e obj/local/armeabi/libnativemaprender.so 0003deb4
```

Which gives you the location of the crash.

Note:

- The -C flag is to demangle C++ code
- Use the .so file under
  obj/local/armeabi, since this is the
  non-stripped version

Also, when using NDK r5 with a 2.3 AVD, it is actually possible to debug multithreaded code.

Comment: Great, Excellent. Thanks for the detailed answer. It worked for me 100%. Thank you and an up vote for you.

Comment: Brilliant, got this working thanks to you - I was struggling using the `.so` file in `libs`, which of course is stripped. The one in `obj` works.

Comment: avdree - I'd encourage you to show the actual output of add2line in this otherwise very good answer.

Comment: Just a comment, the addr2line utility can be used with any (GNU-produced?) binary containing debug symbols. Works for the desktop and embedded targets as well :)

Comment: I am not using any native library except `android-support-v4`.. So is it possible that i can use `addr2line` tool to get line number of crash in java file.. i have added details at [http://stackoverflow.com/q/30093772/1994950]..

Comment: My project logs says #00 pc 0025e520  [heap]

#01 pc 0002230f  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::freeDataNoInit()+22)

#02 pc 00022371  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::~Parcel()+4)
 what adress I suppose to provide for these system/libs file like obj/local/armeabi/libnativemaprender.so

Comment: I wanted to move your attention on the second note: **Use the .so file under obj/local/<abi>**. Lifesaver

Comment: arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line: 'obj/local/armeabi/libart.so': No such file
why?

Comment: @MahendraChhimwal '0025e520' would be the address you would use in your comment above, or '00022371'

Answer (score 49):

There's an easier way to do this now (ndk-r7). Check out the ndk-stack command. The docs are in you_android_ndk_path/docs/NDK-STACK.html

Comment: I tried the first answer by svdree and couldn't get any good output. I tried this one and it showed me the exact line my code was crashing on! Thanks Byron!

Comment: Much easier than addr2line used to be!

Comment: I would very much like a link/resource, if you could put one up.

Comment: This is really good! (ndk-stack.html)[https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html]

Comment: "directory containing symbolic versions of your app's shared libraries." How can we find the shared library for a xamarin forms android application