# How do you troubleshoot an Android system library crash (libwebcore.so)

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash-dumps

My Android webview is crashing and the error dump from adb logcat tells me that *libwebcore.so* is the library causing the segmentation fault. How do you troubleshoot this?

My initial research took me to places like this thread: [How to use addr2line in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314036/how-to-use-addr2line-in-android), which in essence says to get the non-stripped version of the library and use the addr2line utility to pinpoint the exact line causing the segmentation fault

The thread above says "Use the .so file under obj/local/armeabi, since this is the non-stripped version"...but I couldn't find libwebcore.so anywhere under */usr/local/android-ndk-r6* or */usr/local/android-sdk-mac_86* on my Mac, and I only found a stripped version of libwebcore.so under */system/lib* on the Android device.

Is there a way I can get my hands on a non-stripped version of libwebcore.so? Or am I just not going about this the right way?

---

For reference, here is the error dump as spit out by adb logcat:

```
I/DEBUG   (   65): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   65): Build fingerprint: 'google/passion/passion:2.3.4/GRJ22/121341:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   65): pid: 611, tid: 618  >>> com.swishly.gap <<<
I/DEBUG   (   65): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  r0 00000002  r1 002f9564  r2 00000003  r3 008e79c8
I/DEBUG   (   65):  r4 00000000  r5 002f9700  r6 00000000  r7 4470baf4
I/DEBUG   (   65):  r8 4470bb64  r9 44520ea8  10 002ae048  fp 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  ip 00000000  sp 4470bad0  lr a851857b  pc a851838e  cpsr 00000030
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d0  0061006300000000  d1  0064006500680000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d2  0077007400650000  d3  004c006b00720000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d4  007400610063006f  d5  0053006e006f0069
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d6  006300720075006f  d7  0000000000000065
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d16 41d39d979893f080  d17 41d39d9b0a07ff06
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d18 41106a1000000000  d19 4024000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d22 4024000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d24 0000000000000000  d25 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 bff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   65):  scr 20000013
I/DEBUG   (   65): 
I/DEBUG   (   65):          #00  pc 0021838e  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   (   65):          #01  pc 00218576  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   (   65):          #02  pc 002186f8  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   (   65):          #03  pc 0021873a  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   (   65):          #04  pc 0021875c  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   (   65):          #05  pc 0021879a  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   (   65):          #06  pc 0021febe  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   (   65):          #07  pc 00220df0  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   (   65):          #08  pc 0022147c  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   (   65):          #09  pc 00017e34  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   65): 
I/DEBUG   (   65): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (   65): a851836c 602303c2 eb03e002 602003c2 46206063 
I/DEBUG   (   65): a851837c bf00bd70 b510680b b1134604 1c426818 
I/DEBUG   (   65): a851838c 6820601a f7ff6023 4620fd55 bf00bd10 
I/DEBUG   (   65): a851839c 4604b510 fd1ef7ff f6534620 4620fa73 
I/DEBUG   (   65): a85183ac bf00bd10 4604b570 460e6cc0 f6acb168 
I/DEBUG   (   65): 
I/DEBUG   (   65): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (   65): a8518558 d10242a5 2600462c 6823e017 f1b3b113 
I/DEBUG   (   65): a8518568 d1f83fff e7f33408 1d216878 f7ff1980 
I/DEBUG   (   65): a8518578 3408ff03 d00642a5 2b006823 f1b3d0f9 
I/DEBUG   (   65): a8518588 d1013fff 462ce7f5 42ac3604 e8bdd1ec 
I/DEBUG   (   65): a8518598 bf0081f0 b087b5f0 0710f100 4604ae03 
I/DEBUG   (   65): 
I/DEBUG   (   65): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   65):     4470ba90  00953a1c  
I/DEBUG   (   65):     4470ba94  a83da669  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   (   65):     4470ba98  9de0413c  
I/DEBUG   (   65):     4470ba9c  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   65):     4470baa0  00953a18  
I/DEBUG   (   65):     4470baa4  0000a000  
I/DEBUG   (   65):     4470baa8  4470bb64  
I/DEBUG   (   65):     4470baac  44520ea8  
I/DEBUG   (   65):     4470bab0  002ae048  
I/DEBUG   (   65):     4470bab4  afd1362d  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   65):     4470bab8  4470baf4  
I/DEBUG   (   65):     4470babc  00953a1c
```

Comment: have you tried checking why your `WebView` is causing `libwebcore.so` crash? I don't think there can be a major bug in system libraries.

Comment: here is a link to the [WebView source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.1_r1/android/webkit/WebViewCore.java/) that actually loads the webcore native library. I suggest you try to narrow down which native method in there would produce the crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can checkout the whole WebKit xcode project along with the whole Android open source project with the link Kerubu provided (I did a few months ago, it takes multiple gigabytes & hours...) and probably create your own unstripped .so library (I didn't), but I doubt this is the easiest way to take on this issue.

Edit: it turns out android is mirrored on github, here's the [WebCore project](https://github.com/android/platform_external_webkit/tree/master/WebCore).

There is a good chance that your application is far easier to troubleshoot than the WebKit project!

I'll allow myself to throw a wild guess:

There are known bugs with [javascript injection](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19634) (also [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987)) for some devices only that seem to be affecting some html app framework as well (such as PhoneGap, apparently), do you use the method `addJavascriptInterface`? If so there is a workaround, calling the `WebChromeClient`'s `onJsPrompt` and parsing the string to perform native calls from the webview.

Java to javascript:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:alert('toto');");
```

javascript to java:

in javascript:

```
prompt('this is the message', 'this is the default value');
```

and in java:

```
WebChromeClient chromeClient = new WebChromeClient(){
  @Override
  public boolean onJsPrompt(WebView view, String url, String message, String defaultValue, android.webkit.JsPromptResult result){
      Log.d("javascriptPrompt", "prompt : "+url+"-"+message);
      // should log "javascriptPrompt, "prompt: null - this is the message"
      // parse the message and do whatever you want here
      result.confirm();
      return true;
  }
}
webview.setChromeClient(chromeClient);
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I think you're right: I was hoping a libwebcore stack trace would provide some clues because the circumstances of the crash are pretty hard to track, but this looks like a lot'o pain for very little gain. On the other hand, my app does [javascript injection](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19634) so thanks a lot for providing these links

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure but is the source for libwebkit.so to be found in [Android Open Source Project?](http://source.android.com/index.html)