# Segmentation fault in native library when running under Android prior to 4.0.3

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native-code, native-methods

`libFidoCore.so` is my native library, I call java function from this library in ICS 4.0.3 version of Android this library works good without crashes, but on Android 2.3.3 or Android 2.3.4 my application crashes with following log. Why ?

```
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73): Build fingerprint: 'google/soju/crespo:2.3.3/GRI40/102588:user/release-keys'
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73): pid: 725, tid: 756  >>> com.fido.android.framework.service <<<
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000043
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  r0 00000033  r1 00000001  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  r4 00000033  r5 002a8d90  r6 00000000  r7 4051a9c0
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  r8 001dfb38  r9 0000002d  10 804cbc7c  fp 804b4108
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  ip afa03108  sp 44b3bd20  lr 8004be0f  pc 80054a7c  cpsr 60000030
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d0  54454e3a303a655f  d1  006500640061004f
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d2  006800280020004b  d3  006500640061002e
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d4  766f72503a3a7265  d5  2d2d206e6f697369
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d6  2d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d  d7  2d2d2d2d2d2d2d2d
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d16 0000000700000033  d17 3fe0000000000000
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d18 42eccefa43de3400  d19 3fbc71c71c71c71c
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d20 4008000000000000  d21 3fd99a27ad32ddf5
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d22 3fd24998d6307188  d23 3fcc7288e957b53b
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d24 3fc74721cad6b0ed  d25 3fc39a09d078c69f
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
05-21 09:20:17.539: I/DEBUG(73):  scr 80000012
05-21 09:20:17.617: I/DEBUG(73):          #00  pc 00054a7c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-21 09:20:17.617: I/DEBUG(73):          #01  pc 0004be0a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73): code around pc:
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73): 80054a5c 688b0010 0045eb00 0110f113 0144eb01 
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73): 80054a6c ee98f7c2 bf00bd70 41f0e92d b3184604 
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73): 80054a7c f2406903 688174ff f1116945 eb060610 
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73): 80054a8c 23000643 4618462a 5af1e00b 2f7e1e4f 
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73): 80054a9c 42a1d905 3003d901 3002e002 3001e000 
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73): code around lr:
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73): 8004bdec 000411e4 6905b570 2101460c 46164628 
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73): 8004bdfc ff80f006 b10eb174 70332301 f0084620 
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73): 8004be0c 4604fe33 4806b930 49064622 44794478 
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73): 8004be1c fd8ef7f9 21074628 ff6cf006 bd704620 
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73): 8004be2c 0003e892 00041175 6904b570 2101460d 
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73): stack:
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bce0  44b3bd14  
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bce4  00000000  
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bce8  00000019  
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bcec  804e0138  
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bcf0  44b3bd14  
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bcf4  46636a61  
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bcf8  804b429c  /data/data/com.fido.android.framework.service/lib/libFidoCore.so
05-21 09:20:17.621: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bcfc  804cbc7c  
05-21 09:20:17.625: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd00  00000033  
05-21 09:20:17.625: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd04  80000000  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-21 09:20:17.625: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd08  4051a9c0  
05-21 09:20:17.625: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd0c  80468e60  /data/data/com.fido.android.framework.service/lib/libFidoCore.so
05-21 09:20:17.625: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd10  804d8138  
05-21 09:20:17.625: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd14  804b42dc  /data/data/com.fido.android.framework.service/lib/libFidoCore.so
05-21 09:20:17.625: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd18  df002777  
05-21 09:20:17.625: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd1c  e3a070ad  
05-21 09:20:17.625: I/DEBUG(73): #00 44b3bd20  00000033  
05-21 09:20:17.625: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd24  002a8d90  
05-21 09:20:17.625: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd28  00000000  
05-21 09:20:17.625: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd2c  4051a9c0  
05-21 09:20:17.625: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd30  001dfb38  
05-21 09:20:17.628: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd34  8004be0f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-21 09:20:17.628: I/DEBUG(73): #01 44b3bd38  00000001  
05-21 09:20:17.628: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd3c  00000033  
05-21 09:20:17.628: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd40  80000000  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-21 09:20:17.628: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd44  80467009  /data/data/com.fido.android.framework.service/lib/libFidoCore.so
05-21 09:20:17.628: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd48  4058f7f0  
05-21 09:20:17.628: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd4c  00000000  
05-21 09:20:17.628: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd50  0000005c  
05-21 09:20:17.628: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd54  4232a448  
05-21 09:20:17.628: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd58  0000029c  
05-21 09:20:17.628: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd5c  000003bc  
05-21 09:20:17.628: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd60  000005c0  
05-21 09:20:17.628: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd64  4051a7c8  
05-21 09:20:17.628: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd68  44b3bde0  
05-21 09:20:17.632: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd6c  44b3bddc  
05-21 09:20:17.632: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd70  4232a47c  
05-21 09:20:17.632: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd74  44b3bd84  
05-21 09:20:17.632: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd78  804d8138  
05-21 09:20:17.632: I/DEBUG(73):     44b3bd7c  002abaa4  
05-21 09:20:17.953: I/BootReceiver(108): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_02 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
05-21 09:20:17.964: I/DEBUG(73): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
```

Comment: Your code causes a segmentation fault for some reason and you'll have to debug it to find out why: http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2010/08/tips-tricks-debugging-android-ndk-stack-traces/ and http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/

Comment: @zapl but same code works under Android 4.0.3 and crashes under Android 2.3.3

Comment: Yes that is possible since different versions of Android do different things & have different APIs to some extend. The fingerprint just tells you that you have a Nexus S.

Comment: @zapl i have edited my question. And what can I do in this case ?

Comment: Find libdvm.so on your device and check 00054a7c, 0004be0a from the stack after #00, #01 for function calls as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314036/how-to-use-addr2line-in-android)

Comment: Why do you call ReleaseStringUTFChars if you have not called GetStringUTFChars? Show the link (I found oracle one very opaque, ambiguous) where it is recommended/documented. I think NewStringUTF just creates ordinary String object (local referenced) with copy of supplied char array (converted). If you want to release it use DeleteLocalRef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a change in the way JNI references are handled in ICS. This blogpost explains it: http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html

It depends on your targetSdkVersion, maybe you can try to set it lower to use the compatibility mode.