# heap corruption while using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm using NDK with my android code.

while using malloc in one method, I'm getting bellow **error** with crash of my app.

```
A/libc: heap corruption detected by dlfree
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 10197
```

Please suggest me  what should i do to resolve this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333449/memory-corruption-debug-with-android-ndk/11334052#11334052

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memory corruption debug with android ndk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333449/memory-corruption-debug-with-android-ndk)

Comment: Does your code really call `dlfree`? The best fix would be to avoid this call, see https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/287