# Application crash with android 4.0 or higher version

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native-code

I am working on a app, where I will use android NDK & JNI.
Whenever I run my app on any android 4.0 or higher version... my app will crash and gives the following error...

```
A/libc(18556): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)
D/libEGL(18606): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
D/libEGL(18606): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
D/libEGL(18606): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
D/libEGL(18606): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(18606): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
D/OpenGLRenderer(18606): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Main problem is `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad(code=1)`

If anyone know about this... then tell me the reason.

Comment: Your .SO broke. You have a segmentation fault in the C code. Post source, format the answer and maybe we can get somewhere.

Comment: Indeed. SIGSEGV should be a dead give-away.

Comment: There usually is more info in the log, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314036/how-to-use-addr2line-in-android

Answer (score 0):

initially, the segmentation fault and, specially the 0xdeadbaad, would mean a memory corruption or similar but, I recently found that, with the NDK, this is also the default behaviour for assertions: on assert fail it sends SIGSEGV, instead of SIGTRAP, and sets the memory pointer to this hex string.

You should check that your code is calling to assert or, in case you're using third party's software, check that you're passing the proper values to every call. A quick way to check this would be building your library with NDEBUG set to 1 (by default if you set APP_OPTIM := release in your Application.mk) and check if you still have exactly the same problem.

Hope this helps.