# Using debug build as a debug symbol source

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, gdb, debug-symbols

I have an Android NDK library. It crashes on the device, gives me the crash address (0x80C44F3E). The way I build it, there are debug symbols for the relevant part of the code. The copy of the library that I've got in `(myproject)\obj\local\armeabi` is almost 1MB larger than the library that goes into `(myproject)\libs`. I fugure, it's unstripped.

Can I use the unstripped library to translate the crash address into source/line? How exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314036/how-to-use-addr2line-in-android

Answer (score 0):

My way to do it (and it works) : is to copy manualy your libs from "obj/local/armeabi/" to " libs/armeabi/" and then create your apk (using ant debug).