# android - ADB Logcat error

Tags: android, crash, adb, logcat

I got this error, and I have no idea what is happening. Thanks!

```
I/DEBUG   (   78): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   78): Build fingerprint: 'verizon_wwe/inc/inc:2.3.4/GRJ22/185897.2:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   78): pid: 9829, tid: 9839  >>> com.eternal5.election2012 <<<
I/DEBUG   (   78): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000000f
I/DEBUG   (   78):  r0 00000003  r1 00000000  r2 003a9578  r3 003a9560
I/DEBUG   (   78):  r4 00000000  r5 00000018  r6 003a9568  r7 0000a000
I/DEBUG   (   78):  r8 00000020  r9 00357998  10 0033e358  fp 00000008
I/DEBUG   (   78):  ip 00000000  sp 44f4d8b8  lr afd10fc8  pc afd1336a  cpsr 88000030
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d0  3efafafc3df0f0f2  d1  000000003f800000
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d2  0000000043f00000  d3  00000000bf800000
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d4  00000000c4054000  d5  3fd5333300000000
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d6  bf80000044054000  d7  3f80000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d8  00000000000002e0  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d16 bfa5a8b56edbeb54  d17 bfe304e4d987aa10
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d18 bf29dc075e93ddb3  d19 3ec6cd878c3b46a7
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d20 bfd07ff866e96ee2  d21 3fc500b99b47720d
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d22 0000000000000000  d23 3ef99342e0ee5069
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d24 40dd4c2013880000  d25 40ed4c1013880000
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d26 40cd4c4013880000  d27 3ef99342e0ee5069
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d28 c002011d28ebc7c3  d29 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   78):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   78):  scr 20000017
I/DEBUG   (   78): 
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #00  pc 0001336a  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #01  pc 00014642  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #02  pc 000771a0  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #03  pc 000799f4  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #04  pc 00079c12  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #05  pc 00081a26  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #06  pc 0005d92e  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #07  pc 000600f2  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #08  pc 0007389c  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #09  pc 00013242  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #10  pc 0001b3a0  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #11  pc 0009e48c  /data/data/com.eternal5.election2012/lib/libcorona.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #12  pc 000bfc60  /data/data/com.eternal5.election2012/lib/libcorona.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #13  pc 000cb818  /data/data/com.eternal5.election2012/lib/libcorona.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #14  pc 00091508  /data/data/com.eternal5.election2012/lib/libcorona.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #15  pc 00091508  /data/data/com.eternal5.election2012/lib/libcorona.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #16  pc 00091508  /data/data/com.eternal5.election2012/lib/libcorona.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #17  pc 00091508  /data/data/com.eternal5.election2012/lib/libcorona.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #18  pc 00091508  /data/data/com.eternal5.election2012/lib/libcorona.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #19  pc 000c932c  /data/data/com.eternal5.election2012/lib/libcorona.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #20  pc 000921c4  /data/data/com.eternal5.election2012/lib/libcorona.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #21  pc 000c2950  /data/data/com.eternal5.election2012/lib/libcorona.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #22  pc 00086978  /data/data/com.eternal5.election2012/lib/libcorona.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #23  pc 000181b4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   78):          #24  pc 00049f6a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (   78): 
I/DEBUG   (   78): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (   78): afd13348 51acf8c4 1a5be218 f0c042bb 69608213 
I/DEBUG   (   78): afd13358 4283186d 8093f000 2c1f08cc 6898d82b 
I/DEBUG   (   78): afd13368 68c668d9 f040429e 688b8205 f04042b3 
I/DEBUG   (   78): afd13378 42888201 f8dfd10c 2601c428 fa1644fc 
I/DEBUG   (   78): afd13388 f8dcf004 ea266000 f8cc0400 e0804000 
I/DEBUG   (   78): 
I/DEBUG   (   78): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (   78): afd10fa8 e2166903 1a000017 e5945000 e1a02004 
I/DEBUG   (   78): afd10fb8 e2055a02 e1a00005 e3851001 ebffee16 
I/DEBUG   (   78): afd10fc8 e3500000 13856002 1a000001 ea000009 
I/DEBUG   (   78): afd10fd8 ebfffe52 e1a01004 e1a00006 ebffee16 
I/DEBUG   (   78): afd10fe8 e1a01005 e1a02006 e3a03000 e1550000 
I/DEBUG   (   78): 
I/DEBUG   (   78): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d878  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d87c  00066325  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d880  00066315  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d884  0034e9d8  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d888  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d88c  00000006  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d890  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d894  00358510  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d898  003a9568  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d89c  003a9568  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d8a0  003a9568  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d8a4  005864e3  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d8a8  00000020  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d8ac  00357998  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d8b0  df002777  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d8b4  e3a070ad  
I/DEBUG   (   78): #00 44f4d8b8  003a9568  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d8bc  003a9568  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d8c0  80fa855c  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d8c4  005864e3  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d8c8  00000020  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d8cc  afd14645  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   78): #01 44f4d8d0  003a9568  
I/DEBUG   (   78):     44f4d8d4  80e771a3  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
D/CDMASMSdispatcher(  250): NUmem value is: false
D/DeviceStorageMonitorService(  124): DeviceStorageMonitorservice, nv value dis/local: false
I/BootReceiver(  124): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
D/AudioPolicyService(  975): stopOutput() tid 975
D/AudioPolicyService(  975): releaseOutput() tid 975
D/SensorGUI(  124): SensorChannel::write(): write errno = 32, mSendFd = 239
E/SensorService(  124): dropping 1 events on the floor (Broken pipe)
E/InputDispatcher(  124): channel '408976b0 com.eternal5.election2012/com.ansca.corona.CoronaActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher(  124): channel '408976b0 com.eternal5.election2012/com.ansca.corona.CoronaActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
D/Zygote  (   80): Process 9829 terminated by signal (11)
D/SensorGUI(  124): SensorChannel::write(): write errno = 32, mSendFd = 239
E/SensorService(  124): dropping 1 events on the floor (Broken pipe)
D/SensorGUI(  124): SensorChannel::write(): write errno = 32, mSendFd = 239
E/SensorService(  124): dropping 1 events on the floor (Broken pipe)
D/SensorService(  124): SensorDevice::activate: handle = 0x0, enabled = 0x0
D/Sensors (  124): Enable akm: en = 0
D/SensorService(  124): noteStopSensor: uid = 0x3e8, handle = 0x0
D/SensorGUI(  124): ~SensorChannel: mSendFd = 239, mReceiveFd = -1
D/dalvikvm(  124): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1653K, 48% free 8091K/15303K, external 3528K/3906K, paused 161ms
I/ActivityManager(  124): Process com.eternal5.election2012 (pid 9829) has died.
I/WindowManager(  124): WIN DEATH: Window{408eb8e0 SurfaceView paused=false}
I/WindowManager(  124): WIN DEATH: Window{408976b0 com.eternal5.election2012/com.ansca.corona.CoronaActivity paused=false}
```

This happens at random times really, but happens every time I start playing the game.

I am sorry if this is something obvious, but I am new to Android, and dont really understand this log. Thank You!

Comment: follow this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314036/how-to-use-addr2line-in-android). You have a crash in native code of libcorona.so, you can get the stacktrace using addr2line utility

Comment: @nandeesh I am using Corona SDK. Would it work with that?