# What can cause an Android app to die without a stack trace?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity3D game that crashes on a Galaxy S3 (Android 4.3) in a rather well-defined spot, though not every time. This is during an asset bundle load operation, so somewhat outside my reach. (Unity 4.6.1p4)

logcat shows "Process x has died" for a lot of bundle identifiers around that time, including eventually that of my app. 
There's also

```
E/InputDispatcher( 2347): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

and

```
Force removing ActivityRecord{43e59278 u0 com.mygamecompany.mygame/com.unity3d.UnityPlayerActivity}: app died, no saved state
```

But there is no stack trace.

My first guess would be memory pressure, but wouldn't that show explicitly in the log?

Are there other possible reasons for the app to die in foreground like this?

Comment: Had one of these,  it was caused by a shader imported from an old up toolkit (like unity 3 old).

Answer (score 0):

This kind of crash is most of the time a native crash and details aren't always visible with debug log filter.

You can enable verbose log level filter and see what's going on.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314036/how-to-use-addr2line-in-android) may help you to go into more details once you have the native crash logs.

Comment: I don't see any native crash either, no SIGSEGV or anything. I've seen them in other places (fixed now) and they appear in logcat as well as in our error reporter.