# Why is ndk-build producing two different libraries, one very large and one smaller?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, shared-libraries, android.mk

Why is ndk-build producing two different libraries, one very large and one smaller?  And which should I use?

The smaller one is written in a `libs/armeabi-v7a` folder (the build process creates the folders) and the `libs` folder is at the same level of the `jni` folder containing the source being built. The .so file is 747 KB

The bigger one is written in an `obj/local/armeabi-v7a` folder (again, all created by the build process) and the `obj` folder is at the same level of the `jni` folder containing the source being built. The .so file is 6.7 MB.

Comment: "which should I use?" -- the one in `libs/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smaller one is result of running [`strip`](http://reverse.lostrealm.com/protect/strip.html) on the bigger one. The smaller one is packed into APK and runs on the device. But don't delete the bigger one! If you encounter a crash in native code, you can use [`addr2line`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314036/how-to-use-addr2line-in-android) to attribute the crash repport to source code as

```
${NDK}/toolchains/…/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line -e obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libshared.so  0022f9d8 000357bb
```