# Fatal Signal in android 6.0 but works in android 4.0 to android 5.1

Tags: android, c++, opencv

**What I do:**
1. I write the opencv sample face detection code in c++ and call from android using wrapper.

2.I used android native camera and pass image(Mat) to the c++ face detection method.

3.It working in android 4.0 to android 5.1 but while running in android 6.0, the application crashes

4.I tried putting log inside the method where the application crashes(ie) in c++ source code.

5.Sample code

```
std::vector<cv::Rect_<double>> res_dbl;
Rect detect_faces(Mat& image)
{
LOGD("START");
    vector<Rect> res;
    Mat im(image.size(),CV_8UC1);
    if(image.channels()==3)
    {
        cvtColor(image,im,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    }
    else
    {
        image.copyTo(im);
    }

    cascade.detectMultiScale(im, res, 1.1,2,CASCADE_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT,Size(image.cols/3,image.rows/3));

for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {


}
    if(res.size()==0){return Rect(0,0,0,0);}
   res_dbl.push_back(cv::Rect_<double>(res[0].x,res[0].y,res[0].width,res[0].height));
  LOGD("END");
   return res[0];

}
```

6.While calling the above method using

> Rect faceROI=detect_faces(captured_image);

The log "END" is shown ,but its not returning ,while running in android 6.0.

7.I also tried in different devices(with android 6.0).

**What I need to know:**

1.Whether I need to add any flag in Application.mk file?

2.Does I need to make any changes in the above code?

please help me to solve this issue.

**UPDATE :**

1.I build many opencv project in c++ and call from android using wrapper.

2.Only few simple projects(like face detection) are working in Android 6.0 many projects crashing in Android 6.0 but working in Android 4.4 to Android 5.1

3.Is there any changes to be done in c++ code while building the dynamic library in Android 6.0

Comment: Try to find some details about the crash, either from log (`adb log`) or from debugger (`ndk-gdb`).

Comment: @michalsrb thanks for reply crash detail 
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 5588 (Thread-500)

Comment: Can't tell what is going wrong, but that address is indication of heap corruption, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16686223/2992101

Comment: Is there any other thread which reads or writes `res_dbl`?

Comment: @Kornel Not using any thread inside c++ code