# Backtrace due to Sigsegv 11 signal

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am running a multi-threaded C++ program in a Linux system which has android on it. I am getting a crash due to SIGSEGV 11 (segmentation fault). A backtrace generated shows .so file followed by heap with some address.

How to check where exactly the segmentation fault has occurred? How to debug the address which gets printed in the backtrace?

Comment: is a core generated ? can you run under a debugger / _valgrind_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [adb logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) to get the logs. The extra info (callstack, registry) there should help you identify the issue.

To translate addresses in source line use [addr2line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314036/how-to-use-addr2line-in-android) available in NDK

Comment: Yes I used addr2line available in SDK to translate the addresses in source line. Got the line where the crash has occurred.  Thanks for the inputs