# Android '*.so' libraries missing when debuggable flag is false (independent of build-variant)

Tags: android, gradle, shared-libraries, build.gradle, abi

We are trying to use some '.so' prebuilt libraries for our android project. These are:
`mpeg.so` & `lib_arch.so`

When gradle's `debuggable` flag is true, our '.so' files are visible in '.apk' file(confirmed using ApkAnalyzer) and they are, also, available in `/data/app/<package-name>-jekswbj/lib` folder when app is installed.

When `debuggable` flag is set to false, our '.so' files are visible in '.apk' file(confirmed using ApkAnalyzer). But, `mpeg.so` is not stored on device when app is installed. Only `lib_arch.so` is found.

Following are snippets from my `build.gradle` file

```
// buildTypes: debug {}
debug {
   debuggable false
   minifyEnabled false
   ext.enableCrashlytics = false

   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}

// splits: abi
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
   }
}
```

Our '.so' files are stored in `<module-name>/libs/<abi-name>` folder according to their abi(s). But, they appear in `jniLibs` folder as in following image in Android Studio.

[image: jniLibs folder]

So, the `mpeg.so` file is found when `debuggable` is true, but it is missing when `debuggable` is false. What is causing this issue? I can provide more information if you need it.

Comment: Closest question I found doesn't help either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629456

Comment: How do you use/load those .SO files into your app? thru System.loadLibrary?

Comment: @user1506104  I am not loading them. I am kind-of copying them from install location to app's `files` folder. Then, I execute commands on '.so' file. If it makes any sense, `mpeg.so` is ffmpeg's .so file.

Comment: The `proguard-android-optimize.txt` could be removing the .so file since you are not loading it. Can you not use the `proguard-android.txt` version?

Comment: @user1506104 But, `minifyEnabled` is false. Does proguard still do this? I will try this and report back.

Comment: Yes you are right. Proguard should not do this when minifyEnabled is false.

Comment: Its same regardless of `proguard-android.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the solution was to prefix all `.so` libraries with keyword `lib`. Yes, right.

My library names were as following:

Before Change:

```
mpeg.so
lib_arch.so
```

After Change:

```
libmpeg.so
libarch.so
```

And, now, I was able to find them both in the apk and installation directory.

Most relevant [documentation reference](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk) I have found is:

> Note: If your module's name already starts with lib, the build system does not prepend an additional lib prefix; it takes the module name as-is, and adds the .so extension. So a source file originally called, for example, libfoo.c still produces a shared-object file called libfoo.so. This behavior is to support libraries that the Android platform sources generate from Android.mk files; the names of all such libraries start with lib.

And, I am not even using ndk or `android.mk`

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue and this answer solved it for me. My debug build was working fine and when building release I would not have the so files. For completeness, the prefix doesn't have to be `lib_`, it works with just `lib`.

Comment: Updated to remove unnecessary underscore.